# Postman. Set variables for array

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I can't seem to make my code work. Could please anyone explain what am I doing wrong. Thank you!

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("building_ref_id", jsonData.included[1].attributes.building_ref_id);
```

```
"included": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "type": "space_type",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Collaboration Room",
                "key": "collaboration_room"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "404918",
            "type": "space",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "HW Lab",
                "space_ref_id": "$id 32231848",
                "building_ref_id": "Mounting_View-EN-1-Internal_Alpha",
                "floor_ref_id": "Main"
            },
```

Comment: Nothing wrong to me. What error / unexpected result did you get?

Comment: Same here, cannot see any issue with the test code, as @lucas-nguyen-17 advised, please update question with the exception/stack trace returned